# Redirect to a different page when signout is clicked rather than redirecting tobuit-in signout.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

when we click on logout control on "welcome system account" dropdown control(available at top-right of the page). it uses a buit in page signout.aspx(C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\signout.aspx) page to redirect . i want it to redirect to my own created custom signout page which i will manually place in layouts folder. how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a HttpModule and then redirect

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit. thanx in advance

Comment: Hey Thanks for suggestion. I found the solution from (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2007/12/13/using-http-module-for-sharepoint-2007-moss-wss-site-using-fba-and-rsa.aspx and http://vspug.com/dwise/2007/01/08/one-master-to-rule-them-all-two-actually/) and was able to make the changes to my site.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can change the redirection of your signout page using Sharepoint Management Shell command.

Setting the custom sign out page:

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -RelativePath "/_layouts/CustomSignout/Signout.aspx" -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplication"
```

Setting default sign out page:

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -reset -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplication"
```

Comment: That is much better since if you have 16 web-front end servers the module method will become a nightmare to support unless you automatize the web.config modification process. This method is the best practice! Upvoting.